# I am not able to understand Command Buffer and Frame Buffer in Metal. I don't understand how do they work with each other

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, graphics, metal

I was watching the Metal API overview video and it was mentioned that command buffers can have multiple command encoders and command encoders define render targets which are frame buffer specific. But the thing that I do not understand is that how are command buffers executed with respect to frame buffers. What is the hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

To quote from @Dan Hulme's response to "What is the difference in overlay and framebuffer?" on the Computer Graphics Beta StackExchange community found [here](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/5271/what-is-the-difference-in-overlay-and-framebuffer) (accessed on 3/7/21):

> As you've [the asker] understood, the **framebuffer** [emphasis added] is an array in memory that holds all the pixels to display on the screen

The frame buffer acts as a storage for pixel data that the video hardware uses to display things to the screen.

*Render targets* refer to the output textures of the entire rendering process and are sometimes said to be attached to the frame buffer. They are where all of the work done in your fragment shaders (and possibly compute kernels) are stored and are simply textures in system memory, or reside entirely in *tile memory* — memory on-chip in the GPU — if you set their storage mode to `MTLStoageMode.memoryless` in certain circumstances

A *command buffer* is an abstraction that represents an encoding of a sequence of commands to be run by the GPU. Because GPU hardware can be quite different, it would be impractical to have to go down to driver-level implementations each time you wanted to support a new GPU and do work with it. So Metal provides us with a way to manage the process a GPU follows without having to worry about what GPU we are working with. I applaud the wonderful software design Metal implements, and I think that we should all study its power. Since we are working with the GPU, buffers are used pretty much everywhere, so I suppose the name "command buffer" fit naturally within the lexicon.

I am also still learning about graphics and all of the jargon that comes with it as well. Metal adds a whole other set of terms to learn, but I can assure you that it will become seemingly natural when you start to do more things in Metal (and more research of course)